# What's the relationship between the Thread pool in GCD and the Dispatch queues?

Tags: ios, multithreading, threadpool, grand-central-dispatch

1, Is the thread pool in GCD a singleton?

2, How does Dispatch queues access the pool? Is it when a new queue been created, a new instance of thread pool is instantiated and is contained by the queue for further use?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you mean here; there is not any promised mapping of queues to threads (with the exception of the main queue). Blocks are taken from queues and scheduled onto available threads; threads don't "belong" to queues. But the source code is available if you want to explore. https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch

Comment: @RobNapier my question is actually exactly how the block is being scheduled from the queue to the available threads(thread pool), which equals to how the queue access the thread pool, is the pool a singleton or it's a pool per queue.

Comment: I guess the way you're describing it, the answer would be "singleton." It's managed by the workqueue (if compiled that way). See https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/src/event/workqueue.c. But it feels like there's a deeper misunderstanding here. What problem would you solve with this information? Queues do not tie in any stable way to threads. (This feels similar to the common question "what queue is this block running on" which turns out to not have a meaningful answer and is based on a misunderstanding of queues.)

Comment: @RobNapier I guess you are right. The given information is not to solve a particular problem, but to truly understand how GCD, Dispatch Queues & thread ( thread pool ) works. I know that the Thread pool manages thread and assign the free one  with task when ready. And in iOS we have couple of different types of Dispatch Queue and I could not find any definitive answers about how exactly those tasks put into the Dispatch queue are getting assigned to a thread from Thread Pool, which leads to the question I asked above, is the pool a singleton and what's their relationship.

Comment: I would spend time with the docs https://apple.github.io/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/tutorial/ and the source https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch (which I think are surprisingly approachable). You can build it yourself, and watch what it does. Also very useful in understanding "the point" of GCD is the Concurrency Programming Guide, and especially "Migrating Away from Threads" https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

When I read the links [GCD Internals](http://newosxbook.com/articles/GCD.html), I found the text:

```
Note that Queues are not threads!. 
A single queue may be served by multiple worker threads, and vice versa. "
```

Aside from the text, the author has also provided a demo in this article.